# AJAX post with jQuery changing the name of an array parameter

Tags: ajax, jquery, post, parameters

I'm doing a simple AJAX post using jQuery, works great:

```
var parameters = {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'};
$.post('http://api.example.com/rest', parameters, function(data) {
  alert('Response: ' + data.someResult);
});
```

However, when I add an array to the parameters like so:

```
var parameters = {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith', children: ['Susy', 'Billy']};
```

Then the problem is the parameter name `children` gets changed to `children[]` (it's actually URL encoded to `children%5B%5D`) when POSTing to the server.  I can't change the server to look for parameters with the name `children[]` so what do I do?  How can I POST multiple values with the name `children`?  Why is jQuery changing the name of my parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to enable `traditional` parameter encoding.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param

As `$.post` doesn't have a specific option for this you'll either need to revert to `$.ajax` or use the global setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true`.

Comment: Ok thanks!  I'm concerned that setting a global value like that might interfere with other 3rd party scripts on my webpages?  So I'll just use the $.ajax mechanism.

Comment: You can also call `jQuery.param(parameters, true)`, passing the result where you currently pass raw `parameters`: **[jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)**