# Accessing array inside object in node js - undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In javascript:

```
var post = {};
post.arr = ["hi", "hello"];
$.post("http://localhost:8000/test", post);
```

and in node:

```
        var body = "";
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data
    });
    request.on('end', function (data) {
        var post = qs.parse(body);
        console.log(post); // I see { 'arr[]': ['hi', 'hello'] };
        console.log(post.arr); // undefined
    }
```

Any idea what might have caused this?

Comment: If that's *exactly* what you see then you just have a string which isn't a valid object (can't have single quotes or semicolons in JSON). If it is an object and you're printing it incorrectly, then you have an object with a key `arr[]` so you can access it as `post['arr[]']`.

Comment: but why did the key change to "arr[]" instead of arr?

Comment: Because when jQuery POSTs an array, it adds `[]` to indicate it's an array. Many languages and frameworks take advantage of this to automatically parse arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, it looks like somehow the map key is literally `arr[]`. Try `console.log(post['arr[]']);`

jQuery will modify the name of arrays as @MikeC pointed out. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5888057/1861459

Comment: I'm guessing `qs` is the queryString library? See updated answer.

Comment: data.arr gives undefined

Comment: yep, MikeC is right - it's jQuery changing the name. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5888057/1861459

Comment: Thanks for the link.